# How to update an object using getStream?

Tags: javascript, getstream-io

At the moment I'm trying to update the like count on an existing object using the javascript library, but running into problems.

I am following the instructions found [here](https://getstream.io/docs/js/#activity-update).

```
var now = new Date();

activity = {
    "actor": "1",
    "verb":"like",
    "object": "3",
    "time": now.toISOString(),
    "foreign_id": "like:3",
    "popularity": 100
};

// create client
var user1 = client.feed('user', '1');

// first time the activity is added
user1.add_activity(activity);

// update the popularity value for the activity
activity.popularity = 10;

// send the update to the APIs
client.updateActivities([activity]);
```

The documentation also seems to be a little outdated since the addactivity function doesn't exist. Could you please look into this, or provide more thorough instructions for updating objects?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to post your code, we're not mind readers, so we can't tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: The code is found in the documentation for getStream. I will edit the post to depict what is on the site as well.

Comment: There's lots of code in the documentation, how are we supposed to know which part is giving you trouble? And lots of times when people post questions like this, they haven't copied the code correctly into their own script.

Answer (score 0):

In the JavaScript library, the correct function to add new activities is `Feed.addActivity()`.

Once an activity is added to a feed, it may have been copied into other feeds (via 'follower' relationships or the 'to' field on the activity). So to update an activity, the Stream client is used, e.g. `Client.updateActivities()`.

The logic flow in your example looks fine. After calling the last line to update activities, you can fetch the feed once more and it'll include the updated activity.